# Ace Editor cursor position has margined right from last letter

Tags: ace-editor

I know that we must use monospaced fonts. I use `.ace_editor , .ace_editor div {font-family: "Monaco", "Menlo", "Ubuntu Mono", "Droid Sans Mono", "Consolas", monospace !important;}`, but I've another bug, cursor is margined right from last letter.[Click here to view the editor cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4QX5.png)

Can anyone please help me how to fix it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout the Editor Change Font Size to  [ 12px ].

font-size:12px;

Comment: Yeah !! Finally, It works, Thanks a lot Abhishek !! It's really appreciated !! :)

Comment: Happy coding Rajan 